# Vuex + Websocket native: Getting Async State from Websocket within module action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, promise, vuex

I'm trying to populate data using the rootstate from a state coming from a websocket in an action like this:

```
export const actions = {
    fetchChats({ commit, rootState }) {
        const data = rootState.websocket.incomingChatInfo
        commit('SET_CHATS', data)
    },
}
```

The thing is that since the websocket module is asynchronous websocket.incomingChats is not there yet when the fetchChats action is called on the created cycle method of the component.

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('chatQueue/fetchChats'), null, { root: true }
},
```

This is the websocket store async action:

```
export const actions = {
    processWebsocket({ commit }) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const v = this
            this.ws = new WebSocket('xyz')
            this.ws.onopen = function (event) {
                commit('SET_CONNECTION', event.type)
                v.ws.send('message')
            }
            this.ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                commit('SET_REMOTE_DATA', event)
                resolve(event)
            }
            this.ws.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log('webSocket: on error: ', event)
            }
            this.ws.onclose = function (event) {
                console.log('webSocket: on close: ', event)
                commit('SET_CONNECTION')
                ws = null
                setTimeout(startWebsocket, 5000)
            }
        })
    },
}
```

And this is the mutation thats been called when the promise is resolved:

```
SET_REMOTE_DATA(state, remoteData) {
    const wsData = JSON.parse(remoteData.data)
    if (wsData.connectionId && wsData.connectionId !== state.connectionId) {
        state.connectionId = wsData.connectionId
        console.log(`Retrieving Connection ID ${state.connectionId}`)
    } else {
        state.messageType = wsData.type
        state.incomingChatInfo = wsData.documents
    }
},
```

Is there any way I can make const data = rootState.websocket.incomingChats wait until the websocket promise is resolved and I know for sure that there's data to get from the websocket module ?

Answer (score 0):

Any actions that depend on `processWebsocket` should happen after its completion, i.e. a promise should be chained:

```
  mounted() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('processWebsocket')
    await this.$store.dispatch('fetchChats')
  }
```

If they occur in different components, a component that uses `fetchChats` on mount shouldn't be mounted until the completion of `processWebsocket`.

It's a mistake to assign data to `this`, which is Vue instance of Vuex store, it's not guaranteed to exist and shouldn't be used to hold random data. Instead, `ws` needs to be commited to the store as any other data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using [Vuex async and await](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions).

```js
export const actions = {
    async fetchChats({ commit, rootState }) {
        const data = await rootState.websocket.incomingChatInfo
        commit('SET_CHATS', data)
    },
}
```

then in your `created()` hook.

```js
created() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('chatQueue/fetchChats'), null, { root: true }
},
```

You might probably has to add `async and await` to your `processWebsocket` action also.